# How to check django i18n translations with one broser?

Tags: python, django

I have the very first experience of using django i18n. I've done the following steps:

Added to settings.py:

```
USE_TZ = True    
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True    
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'    
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)    
ugettext = lambda s: s    
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

template:

```
{% blocktrans %}WTS{% endblocktrans %}
```

console:

```
./env/bin/django-admin.py makemessages -l ru
./env/bin/django-admin.py makemessages -l ru
```

.po file:

```
msgid "WTS"
msgstr "ВИС"
```

console:

```
./env/bin/django-admin.py compilemessages
```

Now I want to check translation. I'm using firefox browser that sends request.META['LANG'] as 'en_US.utf8' and I get only original content of blocktrans. How to check translations and what I forgout to implement before testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough workaround: add `translation.activate(user_language)` code to your view, where user_language - required locale (e.g.: `user_language = 'ru'`).

For a solid solution - implement code for switching languages or play with browser's locale settings.

See more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference